# How to make a sprite jump like a frog in cocos2d-x ios game using c++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-x

I am trying to make a sprite as a frog which will come from the top of the screen and will go downwards to the bottom at y axis =0.Its working fine as a normal CCMoveTo but i want that after a jump the frog should rest for 1 second then again jump.Some kind of delay in moving.Can anyone tell me with this.I am attaching my code also.
my frog animations are from fly1.png to fly5.png.I just want a delay after each move or we can say that I just want to call the CCMove after 1 second delay each time until the frog reaches the y axis=0
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace CocosDenshion;

CCScene* HelloWorld::scene()
{

CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

HelloWorld *layer = HelloWorld::create();

scene->addChild(layer);

return scene;
}


bool HelloWorld::init()
{

if ( !CCLayer::init() )
{
    return false;
}
CCSize winSize=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

_bgNode = CCNode::create();
_bgNode->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2));
this->addChild(_bgNode, -1);

_bgSprite = CCSprite::create("bg_2.jpg");
_bgNode->addChild(_bgSprite);

float rX = winSize.width/_bgSprite->getContentSize().width;
float rY = winSize.height/_bgSprite->getContentSize().height;

_bgNode->setScaleX(rX);
_bgNode->setScaleY(rY);

z=CCSprite::create("fly1.png");
z->setScaleX(rX);
z->setScaleY(rY);
z->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height+1));
this->addChild(z);
CCAction *a=CCRepeatForever::create(HelloWorld::getAnimationWithFrames(1,5));
z->runAction(a);

z->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCMoveTo::create(2.0, ccp(winSize.width/2, 0)), CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::setInvisible)), NULL));

return true;
}

cocos2d::CCAnimate* HelloWorld::getAnimationWithFrames(int from, int to)
{
CCArray* frames = CCArray::create();


for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
    CCString *str = CCString::createWithFormat("fly2%d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame *f = CCSpriteFrame::create(str->getCString(), CCRect(0,0,256,400));
    frames->addObject(f);
}
//(frames,speedofmovementofanimation);
CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames,0.15f);

CCAnimate *a = CCAnimate::create(animation);
return a;
}

void HelloWorld::setInvisible()
{
this->removeChild(z,true);
}
```

Comment: CCJumpTo And CCJumpBy method use for jumping the sprite instead of CCMoveTo.

Comment: i want the frog to rest for a second after each jump.Can you help me in that?

Comment: id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0]; that is objective c but you use same method in C++.

Comment: sir thats the main problem..where to put the delay..just check out my CCMoveto line...

Comment: z->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCMoveTo::create(2.0, ccp(winSize.width/2, 0)), CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(HelloWorld::setInvisible)), NULL));

Comment: where is the delay here

Comment: Put delay before the move action in it and you want to continue jumping sprite put the sequence method in CCRepeatForever.

Comment: I can give code of objective C you can convert it in to c++.

Comment: ok please give the code..i will convert it.thanks

Comment: CCJumpTo *JumpImage1=[CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:CGPointMake(100, 100) height:10.0 jumps:4];
        
        CCJumpTo *JumpImage2=[CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:CGPointMake(WindowSize.width/2, WindowSize.height/2) height:10.0 jumps:4];
        
        CCSequence *sequence1=[CCSequence actions:JumpImage1,JumpImage2,nil];
        
        [FirstImage runAction:sequence1];

Comment: and to put delay as in sequence as below

Comment: id waitRandomTime = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3];id sequence1 = [CCSequence actions: waitRandomTime,nil];
[FirstImage runAction: sequence1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Firstly, you have to create a frogJump() function. Then,in frogJump() function add the following code:

        void HelloWorld::frogJump()

        {

        CCJumpTo* jumpTo = CCJumpTo::create(1,ccp(x/6,y/8),y/1.2f,1);

        z->runAction(jumpTo);

        }

        Then, in the init() function add the following line:


       this->scheduleOnce(SEL_SCHEDULE(&HelloWorld::frogJump),0);
  this->schedule(SEL_SCHEDULE(&HelloWorld::frogJump),2);
```

Comment: bro,actually i have to perform some action also when it reaches y axis =0 thats why i used cccalfunc in the move action